# calculate average time in sec from two dates in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i use below query,

```
SELECT CASE WHEN val_desc = 'united states' THEN 'USD',
            WHEN val_desc = 'ITALY'         THEN 'EUR' END AS key_p,
       avg((a.end_date - a.start_time)*24*60*60) as average, VAL_DESC
from empl a
group by VAL_DESC
```

expected output as (in seconds).
`2.3 USD
1.2 EUR`

hint:- we have records in tables those (a.end_date - a.start_time) will have 1 sec, or 2 sec or 3 and so no...so i need a average of it.

Comment: Do you actually have a question?  It is not clear.

Comment: Can you please share proper input data and related expected output?

Comment: You have a comma here: `THEN 'USD',` which you must remove and the code will work. I'm voting to close the question because the problem is just a typo.

Comment: @Tejash i am more focused on AVG((a.end_date - a.start_time)*24*60*60) to calculate then in secs. so expected output is to get avg of all records(end_date - start_time) in  sec.

Comment: @forpas , apart from comma there is group by also which will error out the query. I think you should retract you vote. Its upto you, I am just sharing more details with you.

Comment: @Tejash there is no other error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7bdec6/9

Comment: @forpas yes its a typo, i meant no comma there, !! it works but expect output is bit different , eg: - 1st row output for USD should be 2.3 bit i get 18.699.

Comment: @Roger edit your question with sample data and expected results. As it is your question does not provide any info on your problem except the typo.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you want two rows in the result set and the `GROUP BY` is throwing you off.  If so:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN val_desc = 'united states' THEN 'USD'
             WHEN val_desc = 'ITALY' THEN 'EUR'
        END) AS key_p, 
       AVG((a.end_date - a.start_time)*24*60*60) as average
FROM empl e 
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN val_desc = 'united states' THEN 'USD'
               WHEN val_desc = 'ITALY' THEN 'EUR'
          END);
```

Comment: i am more focused on AVG((a.end_date - a.start_time)*24*60*60) , does this gives me correct output, ( i mean avg of all records(end_date - start_time) in secs)??

Comment: The GROUP BY is fine as it is. The only problem is the comma here: `THEN 'USD',`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7bdec6/9

Answer (score 2):

Your question is little bit unclear for me.

So I am giving generic answer hoping that it will give you proper direction.

Oracle `dates` consists of `date + time` till seconds. And difference in `dates` returns number of days between `dates`.

Let's take a simple example

```
First record:

start_date = 16-dec-2019 12:25:01 
End_date = 16-dec-2019 12:26:01
Diff: 60 seconds

Second record:

start_date = 15-dec-2019 09:25:01 
End_date = 15-dec-2019 10:25:01 
Diff: 3600 seconds
```

Following queries will help you understand the logic

```
-- 1 -- average in number of days (around 1/24 will be the result)
Select avg(end_date-start_date) 
From your_table

-- 2 -- average in number of hours (around 0.5 will be the result)
Select avg(end_date-start_date) * 24
From your_table

-- 3 -- average in number of minutes (30.5 will be the result)
Select avg(end_date-start_date) * 24 * 60
From your_table

-- 4 -- average in number of seconds (1830 will be the result)
Select avg(end_date-start_date) * 24 * 60 * 60
From your_table
```

Cheers!!